# Cannot install Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: visual-studio

I downloaded Visual Studio 2017 Community from https://www.visualstudio.com, but when I tried to install the installer not finished to start.

The last screen that I received is the following

[image]

When I clicked on continue, doesn't show the next step.

I'm using Windows 10 Home Edition and I run the install like administrator.

I have been googling, but didn't find any answer.

Anyone has an idea, how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this reproduce? After reboot?

Comment: After reboot the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an offline installer following these steps:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio

Then I was able to install it.

Comment: offline installer not works for me. vs_installer.exe cannot start, no error messages, nothing in Event Viewer. [WIn10 1703]

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a workaround then a solution, but often times with install glitches like this in any application, using the command line installation will resolve it.

Open the command prompt, navigate to the directory where your installer is located using the `cd` command, and then try something like `vs_community.exe -q`. The `-q` flag signifies "quiet" and will install the application without prompting you to do anything (uses all default settings). You can add more commands from the documentation below to customize your install.

More documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio