# Cannot install any Visual Studio program

Tags: visual-studio

I have been trying to install Visual Studio for a couple of days now and none have operated. First I tried Visual Studio Community 2017 and the installer was installed and then the vs was installed but when I try and run it I got an error message that directed me to the ActivityLog file. I've tried uninstalling it then reinstalling it but that didn't work. I came across a solution that required me to try opening it using the Developer Command Prompt which I wanted to do but when I clicked on it from the Start menu it said that the link is missing. There was another Visual Studio program that had also installed and when I tried loading that one, it also directed me an ActivityLog file.
So I uninstalled the 2017 version and tried installing an earlier version hoping that it would work. I can reinstall for whomsoever would want to see the error message as well as the log file.

I then tried the 2013 version (since that is the one we use at school anyway). After downloading the file, I do not even get to an installation screen. A pop-up appears that says that the program requires the Microsoft .NET framework to work 
[Installation pop up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZVg4.png)

The first time I tried it gave me options to accept and continue or cancel so I clicked on accept and continue and that was the end of it. Nothing happened after that. Now when I click on the installation file it just appears as in the picture above with no options. I tried to follow the instructions on [Cannot install Visual Studio 2017 Community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548229/cannot-install-visual-studio-2017-community) since that is the closet to my problem that I have found but it still didn't work.
Please help. I really need at least one Visual Basic to work.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow! This error occurs because you do not have the [.NET Framework installed](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework-runtime/net472). You can download and install it via the link I provided. You should also try the latest release of [Visual Studio](http://visualstudio.com/).  Let me know if any of this information helps. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Hi @TheCrafters001. Thank you for the response however, I also thought maybe that was the reason but when I tried installing the 4.7.2 .NET framework, I got an error saying that it is already installed or there is a later version on the computer so it didn't help.

Comment: So I tried resetting my whole machine hoping that maybe starting from scratch will help. Now I have a whole new mess of errors and Visual Studio still does not work. Now when I try and launch the app, I get the this error message [First error message][1] then when I click ok, I get this error message [second error message][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUhtK.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGDPn.png

Comment: It's ok now. I was using Windows 10 so I reinstalled the entire operating system with Windows 10 Pro and now everything works just fine. A bit dramatic, I know but I ran out of options.